# Connecting to Redux Dev Tools from Node Based App

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools

I have a React/Redux app, *running from Node* with [React-Blessed](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/react-blessed).  It's materially the same as React DOM:

```
const screen = blessed.screen({..})
export function start () {
  render(<Provider store={store}> <App  /> </Provider>, screen);
}
```

Redux: I create the store, with the latest Redux-Toolkit methods.  I'm following the instructions for remote access from [Remote Redux Devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools)

```
process.env['NODE_ENV'] = 'development';
import devToolsEnhancer from 'remote-redux-devtools';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    reducer
  },    
  devTools: false, /* have also tried setting to true */,
  enhancers: devToolsEnhancer
  })
```

I run the node app, and attempt to connect with the Redux Chrome Extension (enabled extension permissions, localhost:8000 in the settings tab).

My state shows undefined... (I have ample initial state and reducers which should at least be visible)

Does anyone have any suggestions or know if I'm missing something?